# Error updating the Notification Hub

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Whilte trying to configure the Notification Hub, I update the Google (GCM) settings, updating the API Key and while trying to Save I get the error "Error updating the Notification Hub". 
Anyone know what can it be? I have a DreamSpark subscription.
[Image of Azure error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEniE.png)

Answer (score 1):

There can be a small time delay (Google says 5 mins, but I have had to wait longer sometimes) after creating the certificate before Azure seem able to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Google cloud messaging for Android under the SERVICES tab in the APIs console for Google devs (Google's API Manager - see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLk29.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try double-checking if your API key is a server key. If it isn't, create one (and delete the other key if you wish), and use that API key instead.

I had the same problem, because I didn't create a server key. It needs to be a server key in order for the API key to be stored successfully in Notification Hub.